# What is the difference between nested ifs and ANOTHER if statement?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic

Say you have a coding section that can be carried out by either a nested if

```
if  then 
else if then 
endif
endif
```

or ANOTHER if statement

```
if then endif
if then endif
```

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: That's not *nested* - that would mean an outer condition has to evaluate `true` to carry on evaluating the inner condition.

Comment: Also please tag the specific programming language that would require the shown `endif` for the first example. Usually only one `endif` is required for this kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit tricky to answer since you must improve the formatting (and ideally specify a language).

Using pseudo code, I think you mean:

```
if condition_1 then:
    action_1
else:
    if condition_2 then:
        action_2
    end if (for condition_2)
end if (for condition_1)
```

vs

```
if condition_1 then:
    action_1A
else:
    action_1B
end if (for condition_1)

if condition_2 then:
    action_2
end if (for condition_2)
```

The difference is that, in the first case, condition_2 is only tested in case condition_1 is false. If condition_1 is true, then action_1 is taken and the if block ends.

In the second case, first condition_1 is checked. If it is true, action_1A is taken. If it is false, action_1B is taken (this "else" part is missing in your question, and it is optional). Regardless of condition_1, condition_2 is checked. If it is true, then action_2 is taken.

As you can see, the first nested block only allows one action, either action_1 (condition_1 true) or action_2 (condition_1 false, condition_2 true) or no action if both conditions are false.

In the two-block case, action_1 and action_2 are considered independently, and if both condition_1 and condition_2 are true, then both will happen, which is not possible in this nested example.